# Prestashop displays doubled cost of the ordered product on the back office

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I have this this issue concerning the order section of my Prestashop Dashboard. There in the order section the price is displayed correctly, but when I click on the name of the customer who paid for that product then Prestashop redirects me to the page with order details, where the ammount of money paid by the customer is doubled. This problem is occuring only on the back office and it applies for every possible type of payment. Please help.

[Here is a screenshot with those doubled values (in red circles)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPGdk.png)

Comment: Hello. Can you support yor issue with some print screen for better understand. Thanks

Comment: I just edited my post, please click at the image link for a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a problem with the payment module you are using, please try disabling any third party payment module and see if the issue appears in the case of BankWire as well.